# QFileDialog appearance change

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I have a QFileDialog. When I execute my code and click a button the QFileDialog is shown. I cancel and click the button to show it again and it is different. Why is that?
Below is two images that show that difference.

[image]

[image]

Below I have a sample code of creating the QFileDialog.

```
QFileDialog *fileDialog = new QFileDialog();
fileDialog->setFileMode(QFileDialog::FileMode::ExistingFile);
fileDialog->setNameFilter("Zip files (*.zip)");
zipPath = fileDialog->getOpenFileName(this, "Open zip file", QApplication::applicationDirPath(), "Zip files (*.zip)");
zipEdit->setText(zipPath);
```

Comment: The one above is the Qt-provided generic file dialog, the one below is the one provided by Windows; generally Qt tries to use the platform-specific one, falling back to the Qt-provided one IIRC if you ask for stuff that isn't supported by the platform-specific one (or if the platform plugin doesn't provide one, but that's not the case on Windows). Is there any difference in how you create/show the dialog the two times?

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: @MatteoItalia Nope. The code is the same. I cannot understand why the dialog changes. :/

Comment: @FouLiNuX: if the code is the same, probably there's something in the context that changes (possibly you are leaking the dialog after it gets hidden?). As Jesper Juhl says, to actually debug this we need the full code of an example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Well the project I work is very big, so it may be something else. I cannot provide with code to actually test it. If I take this simple code and make a new project it works fine. Oh well.. I think I will review all the project again in case I missed something. Thank you for your time. Really appreciate it!!!!!